# Is there a way to fix a leak in the pressurized side of a pool system without digging it up?

Tags: leak, pool

I have a pool that has a pretty bad leak on the pressurized side, and it's not in the backwash line nor in any line that is above ground. Right now I don't know which pipe has the leak in it, but I just had a new patio poured. This most likely caused the issue, although the concrete guy claimed he did a pressure check. In any case I really don't want to have to dig it up to have get to the leak. So I have 2 questions.

1. Is there any way that doesn't involved a lucky educated guess to find the leak without digging up and hoping you were right.
2. Assuming you can find the leak with answer #1, is there a way to fix it that doesn't involve digging up the patio?

Comment: How do you know there's a leak? Are there signs of water somewhere? Is it just reduced pressure? Is the pool level going down when you run the pump?

Comment: The pool level drops dramatically when the pumps are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical answer to both your questions is NO.

One possible solution for you to consider is routing a new line that skirts most of the patio and and then joins into the existing piping near the pool entry.

Comment: You should also try making these new lines accessible as possible. Obviously avoid pouring cement over top. Above ground is easy, but maybe not that nice to look at. If you have to go underground, a trench filled with crushed stone or dirt at least would let you dig it up again and is not entirely unattractive. Mechanical protection (putting it inside another conduit) may also be helpful and reduce the chance of future problems.